# if statement for boolean

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build this simple calculator app
this is how i'm trying to implement it it works fine if it's just `plusButton` but when I add the if (minus) it just gives me test meaning the minus button is true too and doesn't matter if I pressed the plus Button. It won't work I want to make it so it would do other math stuff like (`- + * /`) so can I do it this way and how?

```
package com.github.sinanejadebrahim.Calculator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText;
    String value;
    int first, second;
    Boolean plus, minus;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        plus = false;
        minus = false


    }

    public void numberClicked(View view) {
        value = view.getTag().toString();
        editText.setText(editText.getText().toString() + value);

    }

    public void plusButton(View view) {
        plus = true;
        first = Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
        editText.setText("");

    }

    public void minusButton(View view) {
        minus = true;
        first = Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
        editText.setText("");
    }



    public void equalbutton(View view) {

        if (plus = true) {
            second = Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
            editText.setText(first + second + "");
        }
        if  (minus = true) {
            second = Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
            editText.setText("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (plus == true)` or just `if (plus)`

Comment: thanks @Guy the second part if (plus) worked

Comment: And if you don't need the `View view` parameter in some of your methods, don't use it. (e.g. : `plusButton(View view)`, `minusButton(View view)` etc. )

Comment: @SebastianCăşvean sure i'll check that.thanks

Comment: Hint: if you want more operations, that *solution* would end up with lots of booleans (and lots possible inconsistent states) ... better use an `enum` to represent the operation (`enum Operation { PLUS, MINUS, ...}`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the other boolean to false after a plus or minus is clicked

```
 public void plusButton(View view) {
            plus = true;
            first = Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
            editText.setText("");
            minus=false;

        }

        public void minusButton(View view) {
            minus = true;
            first = Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
            editText.setText("");
            plus = false;
        }
```

also change your condition to something like this

```
     if (plus ) {
        second = Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
        editText.setText(first + second + "");
    }
    if  (minus) {
        second = Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
        editText.setText("test");
    }
```

Comment: if (plus) worked and i didn't need to set them to false after each clicked cause i set them to false on create but your answer worked so thank you (: